# How to handle ViewBox

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, viewbox

I'm facing problem with handling different screen sizes and the problem is **text!**

I have next section:

This is display 1024x768

[image: 1024x768]

This is display 2560x1440

[image: 2560x1440]

On Stack someone gave me hint that ViewBox can help me to solve this problem, ok i try this:

But what is this?

[image: Example]

**When text doesn't fit, it shrinks - that is nice, but how to tell other ( same-level elements ) to take the same shrink level?**

In other words, i want all text the same size.

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="9*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Source="arrow_step_1.png" Stretch="Fill" />
    <Image Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Source="arrow_step_1.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
    <Image Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Source="arrow_step_1.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
    <Image Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Source="arrow_step_1.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
    <Viewbox>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="One" FontSize="20"/>
    </Viewbox>
    <Viewbox Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Two" FontSize="20"/>
        </Viewbox>
    <Viewbox Grid.Column="2">
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Threeeeeeeeeee" FontSize="20"/>
        </Viewbox>
    <Viewbox Grid.Column="3">
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Four" FontSize="20"/>
        </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Embed your `Grid` instead of each individual `TextBlock`

Comment: then it won't be on full width of the screen, i will provide example after 1 h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing your `ViewBox` at the root level instead.. it should look something like this:

```
 <ViewBox>
   <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
     ...
   </Grid>
 </ViewBox>
```

You may want to play around with the `Stretch` property of the `ViewBox` to achieve your desired result. But I'd reckon to use the `"Fill"` option.

I've been using this method for my games and apps to adapt to different screen ratios and sizes.